# Error: "incomplete type is not allowed" while porting project

Tags: c++, templates, singleton, incomplete-type

I'm porting http://www.drdobbs.com/embedded-systems/225700666 to `Keil MDK` for `ARM` microprocessors. The framework compiles and works fine using `gcc` on my desktop but using the `Keil` compiler gives me an error:

`logging/singleton.h(65): error:  #70: incomplete type is not allowed`

Following code shows the implementation of a `singleton`where I get this error. Where does this error come from?

```
namespace logging {

  namespace detail {

      template <typename T>
      class singleton
      {
        private:
          struct obj
          {
            obj() { singleton<T>::instance(); }
            inline void empty() const { }
          };
          static obj __obj;

          singleton();

        public:
          typedef T obj_type;

          static obj_type & instance()
          {
            static obj_type obj;  // <-- Here I get this error

            __obj.empty();

            return obj;
          }
      };
      template <typename T>
      typename singleton<T>::obj
      singleton<T>::__obj;

  } /* detail */
} /* logging */
```

Edit:
The `singleton`gets instantiated here

```
template <typename log_t, typename T>
struct Obj {
    static return_type& obj () {
        typedef singleton<return_type> log_output;
        return log_output::instance();
    }
};
```

where `return_type` is a typedef:

```
typedef R return_type;
```

and that's a parameter of the parent template:

```
template<typename Level = ::logging::Void, typename R = loggingReturnType>
    class Logger {
       ...
    };
```

`loggingReturnType` is forward declarated above the class definition:

```
struct loggingReturnType;
```

Edit 2:
This `loggingReturnType` gets generated through following makro.

```
#define LOGGING_DEFINE_OUTPUT(BASE)                                           \
namespace logging {                                                           \
    struct loggingReturnType : public BASE {                                  \
            /*! \brief The provided typedef is used for compile time          \
             *         selection of different implementation of the           \
             *         %logging framework. Thus, it is necessary              \
             *         that any output type supports this type                \
             *         definition, why it is defined here.                    \
             */                                                               \
            typedef BASE    output_base_type;                                 \
        };                                                                    \
}
```

This makro gets called in a config header.

Edit 3:
Her is a link to the preprocessor output: http://www.pasteall.org/31617/cpp. This file compiles pretty using `g++`. The definition of `loggingReturnType`is the last before the `main` - so the singleton doesn't the exact type but nevertheless it works. I also looked at the preprocessor output of the `Keil` compiler and it's almost the same.

So what went wrong here?

Comment: What type are you passing to the singleton's template ? It looks like the type T is incomplete (abstract).

Comment: An _incomplete_ type is not the same as an _abstract_ type.

Comment: I've added the instantiation of that singleton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the information you put here, the error message makes perfect sense. The code is trying to created an instance of an object on the stack. This object's type is only forward declared but no definition is available to the compiler at that time.

You need to make the definition of this type available to the compiler before it has to create an instance of this type.

Comment: I've added some code for the definition of this type. Is there maybe a problem in order of compilation?

Comment: @Razer Is the config header that calls the macro included in the translation unit (directly or indirectly) before this type is used?

Comment: The file `Logger.h` holds the instance of the singleton and the definition of the makro. The makro gets called in `logging.h` - but that's done after the include of `Logger.h`. I'm now now confused - how can 'Logger.h' instance such an singleton? @selalerer Yes it is - If I produce an error in that file the compiler shouts. Unfortunately I don't know how to output the translation unit using Keil's compiler

Comment: @Razer Try maybe changing the order of includes (include logging.h before Logger.h).

Comment: Hmm, the strange thing ist that i compiles perfectly with `gcc`. The main file includes only `logging.h` and that directly includes, as mentioned before, `Logger.h`.

Comment: @Razer: loggingReturnType must be fully defined (not just forward declared) before you can make, pass, or return an instance of it.  Your instance() function tries to make it, but doesn't know how yet,  If reversing the include order worked, then  I bet the type was defined in logging.h.  Then again, since it's a template, it should be exempt from the rule...

Comment: Yeah and what should I do now concretely? loggingReturnType is defined in logging.h using the makro defined in Logger.h

Comment: I've added the preprocessor output of my project. This compiles fine using `g++`. Why doesn't this work for `Keil`?

Comment: I found out, that it seems to be a compiler bug. Keil doesn't implement the two phase lookup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This might come up when trying to implement singletons.

To add to the accepted answer, as a solution, for anyone else coming here for the same error code. The singleton instance should be a `pointer*` type:

Thus you need to make the private singleton instance a pointer type.

```
class TheSingletonClass
{
    private:
    static TheSingletonClass* instance; // <-- Pointer type; lives in the heap.
                                 //     Compiler will be able to think
                                 //     of this as a plain int. Thus being
                                 //     able to finish parsing the class file.
    public:
    static TheSingletonClass getInstance();
}
```

So as Selalerer's answer states:

> The code is trying to created an instance of an object on the stack. This object's type is only forward declared but no definition is available to the compiler at that time.
>
> You need to make the definition of this type available to the compiler before it has to create an instance of this type.